# Regarding AltBeacon Library, didRangeBeaconsInRegion() is not affected by Android O background limitation?

Tags: ibeacon-android

I'm a user of Andorid AltBeacon Library. The document here http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8 says when App is background, the library can't detect beacon more frequent than 15 minutes. But per my testing, when I set the background scan period as 5 seconds, didRangeBeaconsInRegion() will be called every 10 seconds with beacons collections even when my App is in background. And I tried both 2.10 and 2.14, seems the library in my App is not affected by background limitation (It can detect with any frequency). So what happened here? Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Here is my code to set up:

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000L);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(2000L);
    beaconManager.bind(this);

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect.in");
    notifier = new RangeNotifierImpl();
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(notifier);
    try {
        final Region region = new Region("myRegion", Identifier.parse(FIRST_ID), null, null);
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "startRangingBeaconsInRegion.RemoteException");
    }
}
```

And in onStop/onResume methods of the Activity, I will call

```
beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(b);
```

to set background mode.

Comment: I'd have to see your setup code to know for sure, but if you do not use   a BackgroundPowerSaver you will not auto switch to background mode and you will simply continue to sac at foreground rates until Android kills your app after about 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't use BackgroundPowerSaver and set background mode manually in onStop/onResume methods of Activity. I've posted my step up code.

Comment: You are positive your test device has Android 8?  What is the manufacturer and model?  It is always possible that some manufacturer has customized the restriction, but I think the more likely explanation is that somehow background mode is not being entered properly.  If you can set `beaconManager.setDebug(true)` and attach a 60 second LogCat excerpt (not filtering on your app so it shows system messages) it might shed some light here.

Comment: David, I'm pretty sure that my device is Android 8.1. It's Google pixel 2. And I can see the scan period is switched to 15 seconds while it's 3 seconds in foreground. I will attach the logs.

Comment: @davidgyoung, after looking into the source code of altbeacon, I found the the background scan frequency in Android O is actually not 5 minutes. It's decided by getScanJobRuntimeMillis(), ScanState. In ScanJob, onStartJob(), scheduleNextScan() is posted to be executed. in scheduleNextScan(), the scan job will be scheduled and executed immediately again. So it's some kind of recursion. The actually between scan period is decided by getScanJobRuntimeMillis(). When the App is in background, getScanJobRuntimeMillis() returns getBackgroundScanPeriod() instead of 5 minutes.

Comment: In foreground mode, the "immediate" ScanJob will be started immediately as you describe.  So yes, if your app is in foreground mode, one ScanJob will happen right after the last one ended.  In background mode, the library *requests* that the ScanJob be scheduled to start after the backgroundScanPeriod, yes.  However, stock *Android does not allow jobs to be scheduled more often than 15 minutes in the background,* **so it will "clamp" the recurring job to happen only once every 15 minutes** despite a request to make it more frequent.

Comment: Here's a log line that demonstrates the clamping described above: `06-07 22:15:51.361 6455-6455/org.altbeacon.beaconreference W/JobInfo: Specified interval for 1 is +5m10s0ms. Clamped to +15m0s0ms`  See [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8) for details.

Comment: I suspect that the code simply is not going into background mode when you expect, and as a result the foreground mode scan rates are still active.  This will cause the library to continue to keep the immediate scan jobs going forever.  Will Android allow this to continue, and for how long?  I have not tested this.  There is a discussion of a similar technique [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/586), along with discussion of concerns that Android may close this "loophole."

Comment: The logic to decide whether to schedule an immediately job is here: if (backgroundWakeup || !scanState.getBackgroundMode())

Comment: Actually, whether to schedue an immediately job is decided by backgroundWakeUp not backgroundMode. The code is in ScanJobSchedule.schedule(). Invoking process is scheduleNextScan() -> startPassiveScanIfNeeded() - >startAndroidOBackgroundScan() ->getScanCallbackIntent()->onReceive()->scheduleAfterBackgroundWakeup()->schedule(). So the backgroundWakeUp is always true, which will trigger an immediately job.

Comment: Anyway, the current background scan frequency (around every 10 seconds) is good for our App. I'm just trying to figure out why it's different with what the document says. Per my App, the background scan can continue for more than 1 hour. It stops due to the OOM [issue](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/589).

Comment: The backgroundWakeup explains it!  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are witnessing is unintended behavior of the library caused by ranging in the background without monitoring at all.

In the background, the library uses background scan filters delivered by intent to quickly wake up the app and deliver results on a new beacon detection between regular background scan cycles.  But it only does this if it determines no beacons have been detected recently, because otherwise the wakeup would happen almost immediately, leading to battery drain.

The code shown circumvents this check to see if beacons are visible by only using ranging APIs, not monitoring APIs.  The library's determination if any beacons are visible is based on whether it is "inside" and monitored beacon regions, so if you don't monitor any, there are none.

Ranging without monitoring is certainly supported by the library, so this should not happen.  This is a bug in the library -- it is not the intended behavior.  The consequence is that the backgroundBetweeenScan period will always be cut short if beacons are continually visible, resulting in much more battery drain than the configured settings would otherwise cause --it is similar to constant scanning.

Bug aside, this appears to have revealed a "loophole" in Android O scanning limitations.  Receiving an intent delivered scan will allow renewed background running time.

If you want the unexpected behavior to go away and work like the documentation, simply add start monitoring for the same region you are ranging.

A future release of the library will likely fix this bug, but retain some way of using this loophole if you really intend to.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Yes, I'm benefit from this loophole. Every 5 minutes scan can't meet our requirement. It would be great if the feature release can retain some way to keep the behavior as current.